# Filtering two-dimensional arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of integers like this:

```
var items = [
  [1, 1, 2, 4],
  [2, 1, 4, 6],
  [5, 6, 4, 1],
  [1, 6, 3, 1]
];
```

Is there a simple way to find and remove all arrays with specific values in a defined position?
For example, if I want to remove all arrays with '1' on the second position, the result should be:

```
var items = [
  [5, 6, 4, 1],
  [1, 6, 3, 1]
];
```

If I remove all with '4' on the third position, the result should be:

```
var items = [
  [1, 1, 2, 4],
  [1, 6, 3, 1]
];
```

I know I can do this by looping through all elements, but this seems to take quite long when the two-dimensional array is large (>1000 arrays).

Comment: use Array.filter, combined with a function that looks up values you don't want

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterate over the `items`, use [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter those *inner arrays* which does not have the given value in the given position.

```js
function filterByPosition(array, number, position) {
   return array.filter(innerArray => innerArray[position - 1] !== number);
}

const items = [
  [1, 1, 2, 4],
  [2, 1, 4, 6],
  [5, 6, 4, 1],
  [1, 6, 3, 1]
];

const newItems1 = filterByPosition(items, 1, 2);
console.log('Items1:', newItems1);

const newItems2 = filterByPosition(items, 4, 3);
console.log('Items2:', newItems2);
```